# Invalid character in identifier syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error, pickle

So we have this  code that we're trying to use to load from a pickle '.dat' file. Can anyone explain why we are getting this error?

Here is the code:

```
if os.path.exists('teacherdata.dat') == True:
    with open('teacherdata.dat', rb) as f:
        teacherdata = pickle.load(f)
```

Here is the error:

```
﻿﻿    if os.path.exists('teacherdata.dat') == True:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `od -c` say about that file?

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: You run it at the shell prompt.